# Authorization Header stripped from request inside Docker Container

Tags: python, docker, http-headers, python-requests, urllib

I have a `python 3.x` application that uses `requests` to submit data to an API. The API requires an `Authorization` header. Relevant code looks something like this:

```
the_headers = {'Authorization': auth_header_token}
response = requests.post(
   the_url,
   json=the_data,
   headers=the_headers
)
```

Works fine when I run it on a server or client machine.

BUT when I run it from a Docker container, I get a `bad authorization header` error.

In both scenarios, I get the following output:

```
print(res.request.headers)
{
  'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.18.4', 
  'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 
  'Accept': '*/*', 
  'Connection': 'keep-alive', 
  'Authorization': 'auth_header_token', 
  'Content-Length': '2984', 
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
```

But the team that supports the API tells me my failing request does not contain the Auth header

Good request:

```
{ 
    'x-ssl': 'on',
    host: 'ip1:port1',
    connection: 'close',
    'content-length': '2984',
    accept: '*/*',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
    authorization: 'auth_header_token',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'user-agent': 'python-requests/2.18.4',
    'x-forwarded-for': 'ip2',
    'x-forwarded-port': 'port2',
    'x-forwarded-proto': 'https' 
}
```

Bad request:

```
{ 
    'x-ssl': 'on',
    host: 'ip1:port1',
    connection: 'close',
    'content-length': '2984',
    accept: '*/*',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'user-agent': 'python-requests/2.18.4',
    'x-forwarded-for': 'ip3',
    'x-forwarded-port': 'port2',
    'x-forwarded-proto': 'https' 
}
```

I had originally thought that this issue was perhaps related to an issue on Github [Session's Authorization header isn't sent on redirect](https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/2949), but both requests have `x-forwarded-for` on the receiving end, so now I'm not so sure.

Same code base, only thing that changes is runtime environment (MacOS vs Docker container running on MacOS).

Comment: How are you populating the value of the `auth_header_token` variable?

Comment: In the actual app, it is set else where as a property of a class

Comment: I guess what I am getting at is.... is this populated via an environment variable?

Comment: I've done this with 0 effort on a a mac (how i test), youre going to have to show us the Dockerfile, how you run it, and a simple py file that we can test on our end.. there is something largest at work here.

Comment: @getglad Did you find the problem here?